# How to get the member id on activation link click?

Tags: extension, solspace-user, activation

I'm trying to trigger some code in an extension when a new member clicks their activation link in the welcome email e.g domain/?ACT=171&id=oZYXwJfcAx

I can access the `authcode` using `$id  = $this->EE->input->get_post('id');` and I can detect that the current hook is activation using:

`if ($this->EE->extensions->active_hook('member_register_validate_members') === TRUE){ ... }`

but I can't query the `exp_members` table for the `member_id` using the `auth_code` as it has already expired at this point.

Here's the query I'm trying to run:

```
    $id  = $this->EE->input->get_post('id');

    $this->EE->db->select('exp_members.member_id');
    $this->EE->db->where('exp_members.authcode =', '"' . $this->EE->db->escape_str($id) . '"', FALSE);
    $this->EE->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->EE->db->get('exp_members');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
         foreach($query->result() as $row)
         {
             $member_id = $row->member_id;
         }
    }
```

I'm going around in circles on this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using EE 2.9.2 with MSM and Solspace User 3.5.0 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$member_id` should be available in the `member_register_validate_members` hook.
 See [EE's documentation about the `member_register_validate_members` hook](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/member_register/#member-register-validate-members).

You should be able to query the `exp_members` table with the `member_id` from the hook at hand.

Comment: Yes I finally figured this out from the documentation. The bit that isn't that clear in any documentation is that when you trigger the `member_register_validate_members hook` and call its method the `member_id` parameter is then passed to the hook's method. Thanks @solspace for the reply.